# d3 chart displayed outside bootstrap div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, svg

i'm facing with an issue where in d3 bar chart is getting generated outside div region on each selectpicker selection.

```js
var svg = d3.select("#barchart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Full blown code can be found at the below jsbin location

http://jsbin.com/sodivamiqa/edit?html,js,output

```html
Month,Success_Count,Failure_Count
Dec,32,12
Jan,35,5
Feb,5,2
March,40,2
April,30,25
May,12,10
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhPlR.png)

Comment: what do you mean by outside div...when you do this it definitely draws within the DOM having id=barchart. `d3.select("#barchart").append("svg") ` FYI: your jsbin does not draw anything.

Comment: Thanks Cyril, since  d3 is refering to csv file its unable to draw the chart, but the chart values can be found at the following jsbin link http://jsbin.com/pixicunasi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: what's the #barchart's css overflow value?

Comment: i'm good with this..hence closing the request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

100% will keep it inside the div.

```
var svg = d3.select("#barchart").append("svg")
            .attr("width",'100%')
            .attr("height", '100%')
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```